# How to pass store state as a prop in react-redux-typescript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I'm trying to pass information from the initial state of store to a component where it's rendered, but it's not showing. A console.log in the component itself showed that it was undefined. There is nothing wrong with the initial state, I can access it using a console.log statement in `App.tsx`, so I suspect it's got something to do with passing it down as a prop or it needs initialization with `componentDidMount` or similar.

**reducers.tsx:**

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import {
    TaskListState,
    TaskActionTypes,
    ITask,
    ADD_TODO
} from './types'

const initialState:TaskListState = {
    tasks: [
        {
            name: "testing123",
            done: false,
        }
    ]
}

export function taskReducer(state = initialState, action: TaskActionTypes)
    : TaskListState {
        switch(action.type){
            case ADD_TODO:
                let newTask:ITask = {
                    name: action.name,
                    done: false
                }
                return {
                    tasks: [...state.tasks, newTask]
                }
            default:
                return state
        }
}

//create another reducer for the filtering, then combine the reducers

const TaskList = combineReducers({
    taskReducer
})

export default TaskList
```

**GetTask.tsx:**

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'
import { TaskListState } from '../../redux/tasks/types'
import { Tasks } from '../tasks/Tasks'

const mapStateToProps = (state:TaskListState) => ({
    tasks: state.tasks
})

const mapDispatchToProps = {
}

export const Connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Tasks)
```

**Tasks.tsx:**

```
import { ITask } from '../../redux/tasks/types'

import React from 'react';
import './Tasks.css';

type Props = {
    tasks: ITask[];
}

export const Tasks: React.FC<Props> = (props:Props) => {
    const { tasks } = props;
    console.log(tasks);
    return (
        <div>
        { tasks }
        </div>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass the `taskReducer` to `combineReducers` using object property shorthand, your reducer will be named `taskReducer` in the store, your store looks like this

```js
const store = {
  taskReducer: {
    tasks: [{
      name: "testing123",
      done: false,
    }]
  }
}
```

So when you try to select tasks in `mapStateToProps`, `state.tasks` is `undefined`

The type of the root state is not `TaskListState`, to get the type of your store use [ReturnType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#returntypet)

```
type RootState = ReturnType<typeof TaskList>
```

And finally change the path to your `tasks` list in `mapStateToProps` together with the new type of the `RootState` which will prevent this kind of errors in the future

```js
const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
    tasks: state.taskReducer.tasks
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I just breifly check your script and i think your reducer function is wrong

```
export function taskReducer(state = initialState, action: TaskActionTypes)
    : TaskListState {
        switch(action.type){
            case ADD_TODO:
                let newTask:ITask = {
                    name: action.name,
                    done: false
                }
                return {
                    // tasks: [...state.tasks, newTask]
                    [...state.tasks, newTask]
                }
            default:
                return state
        }
}
```

I hope it will works for you.

Comment: it doesn't work, it creates an error instead unfortunately. it's also not the cause of the  error i'm facing at the moment because I'm not using ADD_TODO. thanks nonetheless

Answer (score 0):

In the below line

```
export const Connector = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Tasks)
```

you are adding the Tasks component but you are not passing a prop called tasks thats why it is showing as undefined try rendering the component in the same file

Or you can do it like this

mapStateToProps and mapDispatchToProps both take ownProps as the second argument.

```
[mapStateToProps(state, [ownProps]): stateProps] (Function):
[mapDispatchToProps(dispatch, [ownProps]): dispatchProps] (Object or Function):
```

For reference [here](https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/connect.md#mapstatetoprops-state-ownprops--object)

Comment: Apologies, I don't quite understand – I'm passing the state of store as a prop, and in the state there exists an array called tasks which I am passing down, so in a way I am passing a prop called tasks? I am not passing any ownProps to the component at the moment.